# nrComm Assign Port

Tags: delphi

I have started recently at the recomandation of someone from stackoverflow to use nrComm library to handle the communication between the computer and a GSM Modem. I am having trouble with assigning a certain port to the component maybe someone worked with the component before and can tell me what i am doing wrong.

When i use the TnrDeviceBox to pick a COM Port it works fine but when i assign it manually like this it fails :

```
...
  nrcm1.ComPort := cpCOMxx;
  nrcm1.ComPortNo := comportnumber;
  nrcm1.Active := True;
...
```

What am i doing wrong. I need to assign COM23 and the component defines only COMS to 1 - 7

Comment: Try skipping the first line, `nrcm1.ComPort := cpCOMxx;`. I think when setting `nrcm1.ComPortNo` to something above 8 it automatically sets the Comport property.

Comment: @LURD thanks it worked! You could post a real answer for me to accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting the `ComPortNo` to a number above 8, the library makes a check with the ComPort property. If that property is already set to `cpCOMxx`, it skips updating the `ComPortNo`.

To me this looks like a bug, but you can circumvent it by **not** setting the `ComPort` property to `cpCOMxx` in the first line.